# ASP.NET WebSite and Sybase ASE Database

Tags: asp.net, database, .net-4.0, sap-ase

Is it possible to use data from a Sybase ASE Database in a ASP.NET Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an ODBC connection from the web server into the database.

Here are the asp.net [connection strings](http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx#_self100) for Sybase:

Comment: Example how to connect or what to do after connecting?

Comment: I've seen more info and I know who to do it :)